# Read all files in folder based on cell input and output to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a folder location in E22 and a blank space in D22.

I want to read the folder location (in E22) and then output all the files to the blank space (in D22).

Though it doesn't seem like what I have is returning anything but the error message I laid out.

*Side Note: Would anything change for network locations?*

```vb
Function GetAllFileNames(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Variant
Dim Result As Variant
Dim FileName As Variant
Dim i As Integer

FileName = Dir(FolderPath)

i = 1
Do While FileName <> ""
    Result(i) = FileName
    i = i + 1
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

GetAllFileNames = Result

End Function
```

In the cell I want to insert the result:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(GetAllFileNames($E$22),ROW()),"na")
```

Comment: Your array was never initialized, so it can´t receive data. Then you need to Redim it before inserting every new element. Finally, you need to transpose the array for it to be in the "column" format or else it will be in a "row" format and your INDEX function won´t work. If the answer was useful, please mark as accepted, i spent some time checking your code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array was never initialized, so it can´t receive data. Then you need to Redim it before inserting every new element. Finally, you need to transpose the array for it to be in the "column" format  or else it will be in a "row" format and your INDEX function won´t work.

```
Function GetAllFileNames(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Variant
    Dim Result As Variant
    Dim FileName As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath)
    
    ReDim Result(1 To 1)  'Initialize array
    
    i = 1
    Do While FileName <> ""
        Result(i) = FileName
        i = i + 1
        FileName = Dir()
        If FileName <> "" Then ReDim Preserve Result(1 To UBound(Result) + 1)
    Loop
    
    GetAllFileNames = Application.Transpose(Result)  'Transpose array

End Function
```

As an alternative, you can use FileSystemObject

```
Function GetAllFileNames(FolderPath As String) As Variant
    Dim FSO As Object 'Or you can use New FileSystemObject   'Reference: Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim myFolder As Object 'Folder
    Dim mySubFolder As Object 'Folder
    Dim MyFile As Object 'File
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Result As Variant

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    ReDim Result(1 To myFolder.Files.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each MyFile In myFolder.Files
        Result(i) = MyFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next MyFile

    GetAllFileNames = Application.Transpose(Result)
End Function
```

Comment: Appreciate a reply but does this mean my code is wrong? What about my formula is that correct or incorrect? A little more insight would be appreciated! From what I've heard FSO is a lot slower than DIR as well, as this will have to run against a list of different folder locations I worry about responsiveness.

Comment: FSO might be slower than DIR, but I doubt you will ever notice any difference in normal use. I always use FSO for its extended cababilities and never notived any performance issue. I have updated my answer, please check

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this when I get a chance and check if it works for me!

Comment: So now I'm getting a reference error. Assuming there's something wrong with my formula. Honestly as you can see vba and excel scripts are very new to me. Sort of just piecing stuff together from online then referencing Microsoft to see what does what.

Comment: I tested it here and works fine. Where is the reference error? if it is in the code, i suggest you learn how to debug, as most errors you can figure out by debugging (a must have ability for any programmer). If the error is in the formula, I suggest you do a step-by-step test. First try in another cell `=GetAllFileNames($E$22)` to see if the function is working.

Comment: Yeah, the issue was indeed the formula. The INDEX I had at the start was causing the issue. (Seeing it used then reading up on it I convinced myself that I needed it wrongly) Though it's removed and now it's displaying 0's after the formula goes through. So, I'll figure it out from here! Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: What path do you have on E22 cell? The GetAllFileNames function should return a list of file names (1 filename per row)

Comment: C:\Temp   - there definitely are files there though. Just sort racking my brain at this for a while now.

Comment: Did you copy my exact code? Maybe try the FSO version. This is a good time to check out how to dubug the vba code, then you can check in each step what is going on to your variables with watch and locals windows.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply! Tested it with FSO and it did indeed work. I'll play around with DIR however and see what went wrong there! Much thanks!